# How should i get the following output in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables Employee and Grade,want an output like Third table (i.e output table) ?
 if its possible then how ?

[image: I Have Employee Table with following Data]

[image: Similarly i have Garde Table with following data]

[image: Is it possible to get the following output ? if yes then how ?]

Comment: why was jyparask downvoted ? (he deleted his answer). I would have given the same answer

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
select e.name , g.grade 
from employeetable e, gradetable g 
where  e.salary >= g.min 
and  e.salary <= g.max
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  E.Name
  ,(SELECT G.Grade FROM Grade G WHERE E.Salary BETWEEN G.Min AND G.Max) 
FROM  Employee E
```